# How to combine Insert Query and Delete Query in one statement?

Tags: mysql

How to combine these both Query into Single Query

`$sql = "INSERT INTO deletedtemplate (template) SELECT template FROM template WHERE id = $id";`

```
$sql1 = "DELETE FROM template WHERE id = $id ";
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can combine these both query using this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO deletedtemplate (template) SELECT template FROM template WHERE id = $id; DELETE FROM template WHERE id = $id ";
```

Comment: heck i coulda told you that.  I didn't realize that was an acceptable answer. haha :)  as its not actually one query but two.  The first query ends at the semi-colon.  :)  I'll shoot you the upvote anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have these 2 queries together, however the same could be handled via trigger something as

```
delimiter //
create trigger template_del before delete on template
for each row
begin
 insert into deletedtemplate (template) 
 SELECT template FROM template WHERE id = old.id ;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

So if you delete something on `template` an insert will happen on the `deletedtemplate` table

Comment: if i put this code in function am getting error as **unexpected create**

Comment: You can't put this into your PHP code, you need to add this directly into mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...  and maybe make the name of your field different than the name of your table... so table would still be template, but change the field currentTemplate or something like that.  I'm not sure if that might be causing any issues but it makes it less confusing to read/edit the query that's for sure.

```
REPLACE INTO 
    `deletedtemplate`
    (`template`) 
select
    `template`
from
    `template`

where 
    `id` = $id;
```

Comment: am getting this Error : **SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064  'as d, template as t (d.template) values (t.template) where t.id = 5' at line 1**

Comment: Posted an update, my query syntax was wrong, can you try the new query I posted.  @KalaiS

Comment: here record is moving to another table, but current table data not getting delete

Comment: So it's inserting just not deleting AND your getting an error?

Comment: Can you post the new error so I can see where in the query it's getting mad.

Comment: i didn't get any error , delete is not working only value is inserting

Comment: this is the code i used there **$sql = "REPLACE INTO deletedtemplate (template) SELECT template FROM template WHERE id = $id";**

Comment: What did you end up doing?  Can you give me an upvote or an accept if I helped you out?  Thanks.  :)  @KalaiS